# varnish rails devise logout configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, passenger, varnish, varnish-vcl

I am using varnish in front end as caching server and apache2 with passenger is running on back-end for my rails3 application.I am using devise gem for my authentication but i am not able to lougout.

I think varnish has a option to clear logged in user session or cookie.I want to know the varnish configuration so that i can logout.

Here is my varnish configuration :

```
backend default {
.host = "127.0.0.1";
.port = "8080";
}


sub vcl_recv { 
 if(req.url ~ "my" || req.request == "POST" || req.request == "PUT" || req.request ==     "DELETE") {
return (pass);
 }
return (lookup);
}
sub vcl_fetch {

if(req.url ~ "logout" || req.url ~ "sign_out"){
 unset beresp.http.Set-Cookie;
}
if (req.request == "GET") {
           unset beresp.http.Set-Cookie;
           set beresp.cacheable = true;
           set beresp.ttl = 360m;
   }

   if (req.url ~ "images/" || req.url ~ "javascripts" || req.url ~ "stylesheets"){
           set beresp.ttl = 360m;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you have to include the logout urls in tou recv function because otherwise you are not telling rails to kill the session.

i would try with something like:

```
sub vcl_recv { 
    if(req.url ~ "logout" ||req.url ~ "my" || req.request == "POST" || req.request == "PUT" || req.request == "DELETE") {
        return (pass);
    }
    return (lookup);
}
```

Comment: I had already tried it but its not working.Is there any other way ?